# Microsoft Office Interop Outlook in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently working on a VB.NET Windows Application with a target framework of .NET 7.0, and I'm facing some challenges while trying to set up Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. I would really appreciate any insights or assistance you can provide.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Public Class frmEmailApi
    Inherits frmBaseForm

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim mail As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Initially, I attempted to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` version 15.0.4797.1004, but unfortunately, that didn't work. I suspect this might be due to the fact that I'm using Office 365 (Build 16924.20150).

I then tried accessing the `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` through the COM Reference, but encountered the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).'
```

I've already tried rebuilding the solution, updating Office 365, and repairing Office 365, but unfortunately, the issue persists.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to resolve this, I would be extremely grateful for your guidance. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

rebuilding the solution, updating Office 365, and repairing Office 365

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project just to test with? I created a new VB.NET Windows Forms project using .NET **8.0** , added a dependency on "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library", declared `mail` in the scope of the form, and did `mail = New Outlook.Application()` on a button click event. I got no error and Outlook appeared in Task Manager. I'm using VS2022 and have Microsoft 365 installed, all on Windows 10.

Comment: (My Outlook is "Version 2311 (Build 17029.20028 Click-toRun)". Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library is version 9.6 and has a file version of 16.0.16924.20054.)

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Thank you for your response and helpful insights. I retried creating a new project with .NET 8.0, following the steps you outlined. However, the issue persists, despite my use of Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. I'm also using the latest versions of Outlook and Office.

Considering these details, I'm thinking to investigate the Registry Editor for potential discrepancies. If you have any specific recommendations or steps related to the Registry Editor that might assist in resolving this issue, I'd greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've successfully resolved the problem, by navigating to:

```
Control Panel > Programs and Features > Microsoft 365-app > Change > Recover
```

This sequence of steps is effective in fixing the issue.

Comment: As you mentioned having repaired Office 365 in the original question, is "Recover" a different option which appears in W11 but not W10? Or did it just need to be repaired twice? (Also, "Quick" or "Online"?)